# how to extract response data from the file upload service in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api

Hi everyone is working on an upload functionality where we will be uploading the excel and I will be getting the response which I wanted to extract I tried doing that I can able to extract whole response but when I tried to extract separate info am getting undefined

my API Service

```
  uploaduserConfigData(files) {
let token = window.sessionStorage.getItem('jwt');
const URL = 'http://localhost:8080/upload';
const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
headers.append('Tenant', 'demoDB');

return this.http.post(URL, files, {
  reportProgress: true,
  observe: 'events',
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token).set('Tenant', 'demoDB')
})
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
```

}

Response Sample which i get

[Response screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySrzh.png)

```
{
    "total": 12,
    "repeatedUsers": 1,
    "emailIdError": 1,
    "mobileNoError": 12,
    "designationError": 0,
    "subjectError": 12,
    "fileS3Url": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/excel/newExcel.xls"
}
```

but when I try to extract total from JSON response it gives an undefined error

```
this.apiService.upload(formData).subscribe((data: any) => {
        if (data.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
          this.progress = Math.round((100 / files.total) * files.loaded);
          console.log('progress' + this.progress);
        } else if (files.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
          this.progress = null;
        }

        this.userconfigdata = JSON.stringify(data);

        alert(JSON.stringify(this.userconfigdata.total));

      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

[undefined response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTz4l.png)

Answer (score 1):

`this.userconfigdata` is already serialized using `JSON.stringify()`. When you say `this.userconfigdata.total` there is no property `total` available. Try to replace the statement

```js
alert(JSON.stringify(this.userconfigdata.total));
```

with

```js
alert(JSON.stringify(data.total));
```

OR

assign the object to the member variable without serializing and access it's properties.

```js
this.userconfigdata = data;
alert(JSON.stringify(this.userconfigdata.total));
```